# Array comparision in node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Consider i have 2 arrays as follows:

```
Array1 = ["123","234"] 

Array2 = [{"keyA":"123","keyB":"rtefre"},{"keyA":"789","keyB":"sdfs"}, {"keyA":"234","keyB":"tyrvfd"}]
```

I have to compare Array1 string with keyA in Array2 and get all those details.

My result should be as follows:

```
[{"keyA":"123","keyB":"rtefre"}, {"keyA":"234","keyB":"tyrvfd"}]
```

I have to avoid For loop as much as possible. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why avoid for loops? This sounds to me like a homework assignment you want us to make for you..

Comment: @Guinn Considering performance i have to avoid for loop as much as possible.. Is it possible to do with "underscore" npm??

Comment: And how do you think "underscore" does it behind the scenes? With a for loop... Underscore is a library written in JavaScript, it's not magic.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Was just about to say that.. xD

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
filteredArray = Array2.filter(item => Array1.indexOf(item.KeyA) !== -1);
```

Also given that it's running in node I'm assuming that you have access to some of the es6 niceties used here (arrow functions & native filter)

Comment: ,,ya i m struggling with syntax.. What i have to use instead of ==>??

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table and filter the items.

```js
var array1 = ["123", "234"],
    array2 = [{ "keyA": "123", "keyB": "rtefre" }, { "keyA": "789", "keyB": "sdfs" }, { "keyA": "234", "keyB": "tyrvfd" }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result;

array1.forEach(a => hash[a] = true);
result = array2.filter(a => hash[a.keyA]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Performance is the concern then you should avoid `indexOf` and do something smarter than that...ie:**sort `Array1`** and perform **binary search**.

I would recommend to use javascript object.
so solution will be as follows...

```
var Array1 = ["123","234"]
var Array2 = [{"keyA":"123","keyB":"rtefre"},
              {"keyA":"789","keyB":"sdfs"}, 
              {"keyA":"234","keyB":"tyrvfd"}]
var map=Array1.reduce(function(prev,current){
  prev[current]=true;
  return prev;
},{});//Creating object to find out if the element exist or not

Array2 = Array2.filter(function(item){
  return !!map[item["keyA"]];//filtering elements which are not in map.
});
console.log(Array2);
```